# How to add public static (css, js, vendor) and use as global css, js in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

My team want to migrate old project to angular. We loves components and aot in angular 6. But, problem is our project is complex and we dont want to rewrite css (js for css plugin) following scope in angular, it's really hard. Here is structure folder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmbyN.png

(alot of plugin use combine js and css)

Q: How to add public folder use as global css, js in Angular ? We just restructure html and diving into components.

Answer (score 0):

Add the paths to angular.json in assets, styles and scripts section:

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "public/assets"
 ],
 "styles": [
    "public/styles.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
    "public/script.js"
 ]
```

Comment: i see alot of articles said that, but we have over > 100 files js, css

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob pattern to do this

By default, the src/assets/ folder and src/favicon.ico are copied over.

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.ico"
]
```

You can also further configure assets to be copied by using objects as configuration.

The array below does the same as the default one:

```
"assets": [
  { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/assets/" },
  { "glob": "favicon.ico", "input": "src/", "output": "/" },
]
```

- glob is a node-glob using input as base directory.
- input is relativeto the workspace root.
- ignore is a list of globs to ignore from copying.
- output is relative to outDir (dist/project-name default).

Detail can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration)